# How to show a dialog in Android at the begin of the method, when it is called?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-dialog, android-developer-api

I am trying to show a dialog while my method is executing. The problem is that the dialog shows when the method end is reached. How is it possible to show it, as soon as I call loadingDialog.show() ?

```
    public void test(View v){
    loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(this);
    loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    loadingDialog.show();

    //......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you need to either launch a thread or a Kotlin coroutine so the actual work can be done in the background.

Comment: I tried it this way:         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(MainActivity.applcationContext);
                loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

                loadingDialog.show();

            }
        });
but it does not work either. Did I do anything wrong in starting the thread?

Comment: That isn't starting a new thread.  That's trying to run something on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried putting the dialog's code in another method and call that method at the beggining of the test method? Like:

```
private void callDialog(){
loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(this);
loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

loadingDialog.show();
}

public void test(View v){
callDialog();
//......
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't work either.